# Instantiate asteroid field with for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MultiSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Asteroid;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
                    Instantiate(Asteroid, new Vector3(j * 8, i * 8, k * 8), Quaternion.identity);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Hello everyone! I need some help with this. I'm trying to instantiate an 'asteroid field' with basic cubes for now, but right now it creates a 20x20x20 field with cubes (which makes sense)

1. How can I make it so inside of that 20x20x20 area, some cubes spawn while others don't (Reason for the 3-double for loop is because it's needed in the assignment)
2. Or, if we completely disregard my code, how can I instantiate cubes in random places within a certain area?

Comment: You can take a random value for the x, y, and z components using the dimensions of your field.  `var position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, fieldSize.x), Random.Range(0, fieldSize.y, Random.Range(0, fieldSize.z));`  and then add your field origin, and offset if needed or offset the range using `(-fieldSize / 2, fieldSize / 2)`.  It wont prevent overlapping, sometimes that is fine, sometimes not.  For example I created a field where overlapping was allowed.  When the 2 colliders spawn inside each other, the asteroids would fly apart which was fine for my project

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Unity’s Random class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Random.html), [UnityEngine.Random](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Random.html). This allow you to solve both this problem and other problems requiring randomness in the future.

At the top of your script file, include this with the other `using` lines:

```
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

You can then use for example `Random.Range(0f, 160f)` to get a random float `>= 0.0f` and `<= 160.0f`, e.g. to be used as the coordinate of a Vector3. Or you can use `Random.value` (which returns a float `>= 0.0f` and `<= 1.0f`) to do something like this:

```
if( Random.value < 0.25f )
    Instantiate(Asteroid, new Vector3(j * 8, i * 8, k * 8), Quaternion.identity);
```

Which would give a 25% chance of that line executing.

Be aware that `Random.Range(0, 160)` (using ints, not floats) will return a random integer >= 0 (“inclusive”) and **<** 160 (“exclusive”). That is, it can return `0` but will never return `160`. Conversely the float version could potentially return exactly `0f` or exactly `160f` (though the chances are small).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
        float randomX = Random.Range(0, 20);
        float randomY = Random.Range(0, 20);
        float randomZ = Random.Range(0, 20);
        Instantiate(Asteroid, new Vector3(randomX, randomY, randomZ), new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
```

I think this does what you're asking. Just picks random x, y, and z values between 0 and 20 and instantiates 20 different Asteroid GameObjects.